# JOINING two colums from single table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm curious if there is an easy way to do this. I have a bunch of columns in a single table. Two of the fields I'd like to read as one: description, materials. Is there an easy way to code this through sql? Do I need a JOIN, UNION, ...?

Comment: try concat to join two columns of a single table

Comment: try `col1+col2 AS col1n2` http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-as.html

Comment: Why downvote me? I thought it was an honest question. And thanks guys for all the correct answers. I saw CONCAT used but it was posted in an Access forum, so I didn't think it applied to sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column1, column2) merged_column
FROM table
```

Then, fetch the column named `merged_column` from the result set:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT CONCAT(column1, column2) merged_column FROM table");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $merged_column = $row["merged_column"];
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary example usage with `mysql_*` functions. If you change it to PDO/Mysqli or remove it, that'd probably be better.

Comment: he mentioned `php` and `sql`, but really no `mysql`. promoting pdo/mysqli is better for beginners anyways. if somebody asks me how to write the letter "q" and you show them, you don't start from the bottom of the letter or hold your pencil wrong...

Comment: @Nile: His all other posts are about mysql. Funny that the only upvoted answer doesn't even have valid syntax!

Comment: (I updated my comment ^ with the letter analogy). I've uv'd anyways

Comment: Regardless of the request of NOT using MySQL it is the only thing I've learned to date, and in fact his added code of php does in fact help me. Ty Joao. Nile as I mentioned until your post previously I haven't ever heard of PDO, but in fact have done some reading on it the last few days, and in future will be trying to code using it. Perhaps with more questions. But thank again for that post

Answer (score 2):

Concat function can join two columns of the same table
Example

```
  SELECT CONCAT(column1 name, column2 name)
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **[`CONCAT()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)**

Ex

```
SELECT CONCAT('Hello', ' ', 'World')
```

will result

```
Hello World
```